# How to search nested property in sails js rest api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, sails.js, axios

Have an api endpoint created in sails js. i can query that end point using POST and passing search options like:

```
{
    "taskCode":"COMPLIANCE",
    "status":"PENDING",
}
```

however i have some fields that contain objects and want to query them

```
{
    "taskCode":"COMPLIANCE",
    "status":"PENDING",
    "job": {
        "description": "u"
    }
}
```

Also tried

```
{
    "taskCode":"COMPLIANCE",
    "status":"PENDING",
    "job.description": "u"
}
```

here job is an object and description is a property of that object.

How can this be done?

Comment: I doubt that `"job.description":"u"` is valid JSON format

Comment: its json sent in a post to sails/waterline api, i'll update the questions with another example of what i've used.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you also setting up the API, or just writing queries? If you have set up the API, can you post the code for your action as well?

Comment: @streleck just writing queries, someone else has done the api using sails js

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? It sounds it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
// var x = joson code
x['job.description'];
```

You can see this post https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: I'm using a sails js rest api, the json i'm sending is in the POST query

Answer (score 0):

In case of Sails js you can use

```
    CollectionName.find{
    {
      "taskCode":"COMPLIANCE",
      "status":"PENDING",
      "job.description": "u"
    }).({ enableExperimentalDeepTargets: true });
```

for nested search using find query